# How can I remove a signature once it's saved in Preview.app?

Tags: macos, preview

How can I delete a signature that I inserted using Preview.app?

I can edit or delete all the text fields but the signature seems locked somehow.

Comment: What kind of file is it ? Image ? pdf ?

Comment: Its a pdf. I originally created the file (a form) in Illustrator but overwrote the original with Preview. When I reopen it in Illustrator the text gets broken, so I am faced with recreating the original form again.

Comment: Are you deleting the signature that's stored in the Preview app or wanting to modify a document that you signed and saved using preview?

Comment: bmike. I want to modify a document that I signed and saved using Preview. I haven't tried deleting the signature that is stored in the app.

Answer (score 11):

A possibility is to try
File > Revert To > Browse all versions...

though I guess it will depend on how far back that version history goes. I've been unable to discover just how far back that would be & for how long it may be saved.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove a Preview.app signature in Yosemite. This is a bug. It would almost make sense if signing a document froze the entire document,but you can edit every other annotation.

I've tried masking a signature with a filled box, then overlaying a signature on that. It seems to work and the document saves, but on opening tne new signature is gone. (Another bug.)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it by using a rectangular annotation via Tools -> Annotate -> Rectangle. Make sure it covers the signature and just make the background and border match the color of your document background (white in my case).

Comment: This seems to not work when trying to draw new signatures on top as they always get placed below the rectangle

Answer (score 1):

Even on Mojave it still seems to be the case that once you have saved the file and re-opened it, you will not be able to remove the image.

To resolve this I followed the instructions in [Use Preview to combine PDFs on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202945) to add a copy of the blank signature page from the original to my modified document. I was then able to edit and sign that newly-added page and so complete the document.